# What Event ID is generated when a scheduled task fails in Windows Server 2003?

Tags: windows-server-2003, scheduled-task, windows-event-log

If a scheduled task fails on Windows Server 2003, is anything written to the event log?  And if so, what Event ID does it have so I can set an [Event Trigger](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490901.aspx) to look for it, and email me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Scheduled Tasks in Server 2003 do not make use of the Event Log.  [They log to a text file, `SchedLgU.txt` under `\Windows\Tasks\`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc783861%28v=ws.10%29.aspx).  The simplest way I've found to generate emails based on that log is with PowerShell.

`Select-String "\* error"` should be able to find any failures in the log, and after that, it's just a matter of triggering an email when that's found... and ironically, yes, it's probably easiest to run your script to scan for Scheduled Tasks failures as a Scheduled Task.

Comment: hmm my server doesn't seem to have that file, do you have to turn it on?  I've seen other places where people say it's named `tasks.csv`...

Comment: @leeand00 It should be there by default, [but it's not visible through the GUI, because the Tasks folder is one of those bloody special folders](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic142809-5-1.aspx).  Run a `dir` against the folder from PowerShell or cmd and it should show up just fine. (At least, it did on the handful of 2003 servers I'm still stuck with.)

Comment: @leeand00 - from the Scheduled Tasks window select the Advanced menu and then select  View Log.